# How to serving a django with Apache and Cherrypy

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, apache, cherrypy

I have a problem and would like a help! I have a django application, which is on an apache server. It was running normally until you upgraded to django 2.0.5.

The application is served with cherrypy and apache. Where apache does the reverse proxy role. When I type the address, it removes the targeting created by apache. For example: The domain is "www.example.com" and the application is located at "www.example.com/app". When entering the address of the application in the browser, it redirects to the login page, but removing "/app/", thus making "www.example.com/security/enter", when it should be "www.example.com/app/security/enter".

If I manually put the "/app/" system works normally, server the static files and everything else, but when requesting a new page, it always removes the "/app/", forcing it to manually put to work.

Below is the template I used to get the application up and running:

**File app.conf in /etc/httpd/conf.d/:**

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ServerName example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /app/ http://example.com:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://example.com:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

**File cps.py (cherrypy script):**

```
#!/opt/app/env/bin python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "app.settings"

import cherrypy
import django
django.setup()
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler


class DjangoApplication(object):
    HOST = "0.0.0.0"
    PORT = 8000

    def mount_static(self, url, root):
        config = {
            'tools.staticdir.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir': root,
            'tools.expires.on': True,
            'tools.expires.secs': 86400
        }
        cherrypy.tree.mount(None, url, {'/app/': config})

    def run(self):
        cherrypy.config.update({
            'server.socket_host': self.HOST,
            'server.socket_port': self.PORT,
            'engine.autoreload_on': False,
            'log.screen': True
        })

        self.mount_static(settings.STATIC_URL, settings.STATIC_ROOT)

        cherrypy.log("Load application app")
        cherrypy.tree.graft(WSGIHandler())
        cherrypy.engine.start()
        cherrypy.engine.block()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DjangoApplication().run()
```

I do not believe the problem is related to updating django in version 1.11 to 2.0.5, because in the development environment it works normally. The app ran for a couple of days, but when I need to update a view, I got this problem.

It works in virtualenv with Python 3.6. I've researched a lot, but I can not find something that leads me to error, so I'm resorting to this topic, because I always find a lot of good things here! Thanks and sorry for my english, it's basic!